# What do I do if I want UINavigationController functionality without a navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, navigation, controller, modal-dialog

I know that a UINavigationController has good view pushing methods. But let's say that I don't want to use a UINavigationController because I don't want the bar on the top of the screen. Is there a specific way to push and pop views as I want them?

Also, when should I use presentModalViewController and when shouldn't I?

Thanks,
Anthony

**UPDATE:**

What about adding a subview to a view?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "adding a subview to a view"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

or set it via IB.

If you have a navigation structure of depth 2 or more, it is always right to use a UINavigationController object but when you have only two related views where one of them supplements the other, you can use a modal view controller.